# Crash iOS app: ZL36GetSFTrimCharSetForChineseOrJapanesePPK9TFontInfo_block_invoke

Tags: ios, objective-c

I find in my XCode "Organizer" the error "ZL36GetSFTrimCharSetForChineseOrJapanesePPK9TFontInfo_block_invoke". I tried to set my iPhone in Japanese or Chinese, but the error does not occur. 
What could be causing this error and how can I solve it?
I am sorry for my bad English.

This is the crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x22475196 CFStringHasPrefix + 10 (CFInternal.h:627)
1   CoreText                        0x247af94e ___ZL36GetSFTrimCharSetForChineseOrJapanesePPK9TFontInfo_block_invoke + 158 (SplicedFontSupport.cpp:8959)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x220c180e _dispatch_client_callout + 22 (init.c:819)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x220d3172 dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 62 (once.c:60)
4   CoreText                        0x24761360 MakeSpliceDescriptor(unsigned long) + 648 (once.h:68)
5   CoreText                        0x2474d84e TSplicedFontStashImp::CopySpliceFontAtIndex(long) const + 74 (TDescriptorSource.cpp:3694)
6   CoreText                        0x247a9ea0 TSplicedFontStashImp::CopySplicedDescriptorForName(__CFString const*, bool) const + 32 (TDescriptorSource.cpp:3705)
7   CoreText                        0x2474cbca TSplicedFontStashImp::CopySplicedDescriptorsForRequest(__CFDictionary const*, unsigned long) const + 134 (TDescriptorSource.cpp:3727)
8   CoreText                        0x247a84c4 TDescriptorSource::CopyDescriptorsForRequest(__CFDictionary const*, __CFSet const*, CFComparisonResult (*)(void const*, void const*, void*), void*, unsigned long, TCFRef<__CFArray const*>*) const + 172 (TDescriptorSource.cpp:3630)
9   CoreText                        0x2474c0ea TDescriptorSource::CopyDescriptorForRequest(__CFDictionary const*, __CFSet const*, CFComparisonResult (*)(void const*, void const*, void*), void*, unsigned long) const + 86 (TDescriptorSource.cpp:1663)
10  CoreText                        0x2474bf1c TDescriptor::CreateMatchingDescriptorInternal(__CFSet const*, bool) const + 424 (TDescriptor.cpp:538)
11  CoreText                        0x2474bca8 TDescriptor::InitBaseFont(bool) + 24 (TDescriptor.cpp:642)
12  CoreText                        0x2475eaa2 TDescriptor::CreateMatchingDescriptor(__CFSet const*, float, unsigned long) const + 278 (TDescriptor.h:62)
13  CoreText                        0x2475e942 CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor + 34 (CTFont.cpp:93)
14  CoreText                        0x2475d85a CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage + 22 (CTFont.cpp:152)
15  UIFoundation                    0x26a7531c +[UIFont systemFontOfSize:traits:] + 360 (UIFont.m:279)
16  UIKit                           0x26ad6216 -[UILabel _commonInit] + 86 (UILabel.m:504)
17  UIKit                           0x26ad60b0 -[UILabel initWithFrame:] + 76 (UILabel.m:531)
18  UIKit                           0x26aeeaf4 -[UIView init] + 44 (UIView.m:2343)
19  UIKit                           0x26b6ed28 -[UINavigationItemView initWithNavigationItem:] + 196 (UINavigationBar.m:9834)
20  UIKit                           0x26debe9e -[UINavigationItem _defaultTitleView] + 130 (UINavigationBar.m:1469)
21  UIKit                           0x26b6ec34 -[UINavigationItem _titleView] + 116 (UINavigationBar.m:1479)
22  UIKit                           0x26c094bc -[UINavigationBar _removeItemsFromSuperview:] + 140 (UINavigationBar.m:6931)
23  UIKit                           0x26deed7c -[UINavigationBar _setDecodedItems:] + 496 (UINavigationBar.m:2697)
24  UIKit                           0x26dee99c -[UINavigationBar initWithCoder:] + 484 (UINavigationBar.m:2662)
25  UIKit                           0x2709910e UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 782 (UINibDecoder.m:705)
26  UIKit                           0x27098df4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 296 (UINibDecoder.m:792)
27  UIKit                           0x26deaf16 -[UINavigationItem initWithCoder:] + 734 (UINavigationBar.m:548)
28  UIKit                           0x2709910e UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 782 (UINibDecoder.m:705)
29  UIKit                           0x27098df4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 296 (UINibDecoder.m:792)
30  UIKit                           0x26f814a4 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 160 (UIRuntimeConnection.m:23)
31  UIKit                           0x2709910e UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 782 (UINibDecoder.m:705)
32  UIKit                           0x270990a0 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 672 (UINibDecoder.m:602)
33  UIKit                           0x27098df4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 296 (UINibDecoder.m:792)
34  UIKit                           0x26f80a0a -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1110 (UINib.m:345)
35  UIKit                           0x26e33aa2 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 322 (UIViewController.m:2309)
36  UIKit                           0x26c06ffa -[UIViewController loadView] + 142 (UIViewController.m:2438)
37  UIKit                           0x26acca1e -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 150 (UIViewController.m:2537)
38  UIKit                           0x26acc970 -[UIViewController view] + 24 (UIViewController.m:2598)
39  UIKit                           0x26ad3638 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 68 (UIWindow.m:1445)
40  UIKit                           0x26ad0b3c -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 276 (UIWindow.m:1529)
41  UIKit                           0x26b45a5c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48 (UIWindow.m:4929)
42  Electrical Calculations FREE    0x0008bb68 0x4d000 + 256872
43  UIKit                           0x26b41784 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 392 (UIApplication.m:1865)
44  UIKit                           0x26d692d0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3080 (UIApplication.m:2112)
45  UIKit                           0x26d6d284 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1588 (UIApplication.m:3355)
46  UIKit                           0x26d8183c __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke3286 + 36 (UIApplication.m:12263)
47  UIKit                           0x26d6a7b2 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 134 (UIApplication.m:2748)
48  FrontBoardServices              0x23bf6c06 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 18 (FBSSerialQueue.m:158)
49  FrontBoardServices              0x23bf6ab8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 224 (FBSSerialQueue.m:177)
50  FrontBoardServices              0x23bf6db8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 48 (FBSSerialQueue.m:206)
51  CoreFoundation                  0x22515dfe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14 (CFRunLoop.c:1761)
52  CoreFoundation                  0x225159ec __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 452 (CFRunLoop.c:1807)
53  CoreFoundation                  0x22513d5a __CFRunLoopRun + 794 (CFRunLoop.c:2536)
54  CoreFoundation                  0x22463228 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
55  CoreFoundation                  0x22463014 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108 (CFRunLoop.c:2844)
56  UIKit                           0x26b3ac3c -[UIApplication _run] + 524 (UIApplication.m:2578)
57  UIKit                           0x26b35188 UIApplicationMain + 144 (UIApplication.m:3772)
58  Electrical Calculations FREE    0x00082920 0x4d000 + 219424
59  libdyld.dylib                   0x2210b872 start + 2 (start_glue.s:64)
```

Comment: Have you fix it? I have same issue :(

Comment: Unfortunately it has not been solved

Comment: You say the error is shown in "Organizer" but show an exception call stack. Can you confirm if this error is showing up in the 'normal' XCode views or really in the separate "Organizer"? Have you got an [exception breakpoint](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions) set and if so can you show us the code where the error occurs?

Comment: The crash looks related to loading fonts in a UINavigationItem loaded from a nib or storyboard.  Are you using any custom fonts in your app? did you try loading your UINavigationItem with code instead of a storyboard?

Comment: I confirm that the error is in a separate Organizer, in my tests it never occurred. I have not set any exception breakpoint. I do not use custom fonts in my Nibs and I created the Navigation Bar through Interface Builder. I also tried the "Zombies" in Instruments (simulating Memory Warning) but the error does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an object was deallocated even after having a reference to that object, thus the code assumed it was valid.
Please try running "Zombies" in Instruments. It will tell you where you sent a message to an invalid object. If you are using iOS Simulator, try to do Hardware -> Simulate Memory Warning, as frequently as possible while trying to reproduce the crash.